# Show that, in a normal coordinate chart, $\Gamma^{i}_{(x)(jk)}(p)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, connections

I am currently working through the following proof and have a question regarding the computations done by the author:

---

**Theorem**: Let $(M, \mathcal{O}, \mathcal{A}, \nabla )$ be an arbitrary affine manifold and let $p \in M$. Then one can construct a chart $(U,x) \in \mathcal{A}$ with $p \in U$ such that $\Gamma^{i}_{(x)(jk)}(p)=0$, where $$\Gamma^{i}_{(x)(jk)}= \frac{1}{2}(\Gamma^{i}_{(x)jk}-\Gamma^{i}_{(x)kj})$$ with respect to the chart $(U,x)$ (denoted with a subscript in the gamma terms).

**Proof:** Let $(V,y) \in \mathcal{A}$ be any chart with $p \in V$. Thus, in general, $\Gamma^{i}_{(x)(jk)}(p) \neq 0$. Now consider a new chart $(U,x)$ where the chart transition map is given by

$$(x \circ y^{-1})(\alpha^{1},…, \alpha^{\text{dim}M}) := \alpha^{i} - \frac{1}{2}\alpha^{j}\alpha^{k}\Gamma^{i}_{(y)(jk)}(p)$$ where $y(p) = (\alpha^{1},…, \alpha^{\text{dim}M}) $. Now, this is where I am having trouble understanding: the author considers the change of vector components under change of chart

$$
\partial_{j}(x^{i} \circ y^{-1})(y(p)) = \delta^{i}_{j} - \alpha^{m}\Gamma^{i}_{(y)(jm)}(p).
$$

I see how we obtain $\delta^{i}_{j}$, but how does one obtain the second term $-\alpha^{m}\Gamma^{i}_{(y)(jm)}(p)$ after differentiating? I don’t think I’m understanding how we differentiate the connection coefficients here, but these are all the steps the author gave so I’m not seeing how we arrive at this result; any help is appreciated.

**Note**: the rest of the proof is not pictured, but one can probably see how this leads to the symmetric part vanishing and the anti symmetric part surviving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should have said $y(p)=(0,\dots, 0)$, so because of this, the $\Gamma^{i}_{(y)\,jk}(p)$ are just numbers, so they come out of all the derivatives, i.e you do not differentiate them at all.

Anyway, let me outline how you can figure out the result ‘from scratch’.

- Fix a point $p\in M$
- Fix a chart $(V,y)$ around the given point $p$ such that $y(p)=0$.
- Construct a new chart $(U,x)$ around $p$ such that the transition map $x\circ y^{-1}$ is quadratic, i.e fix some numbers $A^{i}_{\,j}, B^{i}_{jk}\in\Bbb{R}$ and consider $(x^i\circ y^{-1})(\alpha^1,\dots,\alpha^n):=A^{i}_{\,j}\alpha^j+B^{i}_{jk}\alpha^j\alpha^k$.

Note that in order for this to actually be well-defined, we should assume that the matrix $[A^{i}_{\,j}]$ is invertible, because then the usual derivative of $x\circ y^{-1}$ at the origin will be the matrix $A$, which is invertible, so by the inverse function theorem, upon restricting to smaller neighborhoods, we get a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism. Ok, so let’s suppose we shrink all the neighborhoods small enough. Now, calculate the following:

- what is $x(p)$?
- what is $\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j}(p)$?
- what is $\frac{\partial^2x^i}{\partial y^j\partial y^k}(p)$?

This should be a trivial calculation, because we’re simply dealing with polynomials. With this information, and the knowledge of how the $\Gamma^{i}_{(x)\,jk}(p)$ is related to the $\Gamma$’s in the $y$ chart, you should be able to figure out how to choose the numbers $A^{i}_{\,j}$ and $B^{i}_{\,jk}$ in order to ensure such and such property of the $\Gamma$ in the new $x$ chart (at the single point $p$).

Finally you may wonder what prompted me to consider such quadratic changes of variables? The answer is simply that the transformation property of the $\Gamma$’s involves both the first and second derivatives of the chart-transition map. So, if I want to modify $\Gamma$’s at a point, then I need to ensure I am able to modify the first and second derivatives of the chart-transition as I wish; and finally quadratic polynomials are the simplest such functions.

Comment: Peek-a-boo - Thank you for the thought you put into this answer. A few follow up questions if you don’t mind: 1) why do we care about $x(p)$ when we’re considering the chart transition map $(x \circ y^{-1})$ that evaluates points $y(p) \in V$? 2) I just noticed this, but can we multiply the alphas $\alpha^{j} \alpha^{k}$ to get an alpha squared - that way when we differentiate we annihilate the $1/2$? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don’t need to know $x(p)$ I just posed that since it’s a natural question. What do you mean “can we multiply the alphas”?

Comment: Peek-a-boo: Ah, I see thank you. Also, I mean how do we get the $- \alpha^{m}\Gamma^{i}_{(y)(jm)}(p)$ from differentiating $\frac{1}{2}\alpha^{j}\alpha^{k}\Gamma^{i}_{(y)(jk)}(p)$? I'm sure it's some silly differentiation operation I'm not picking up.

Comment: First do the differentiation I asked you to do. If you’re confused, write it out in 1d. Then in 2D explicitly. It’s the product rule literally for polynomials.

Comment: There’s a reason I’m not giving you the answer directly but rather making you work through this “longer” exercise. It’s exactly so you figure out for yourself where the factors of 2 go, and symmetry/anti-symmetry is used.

Comment: Peek-a-boo: Thank you for making me work for it, I prefer it actually! :) I know I accepted your answer, but I wanted to double check my work for the $2$-dimensional case if you don't mind: I think it's easy to see where $- \alpha^{m}\Gamma^{i}_{(y)(jm)}(p)$ comes from since, e.g. once we differentiate and simplify we get, $\frac{\partial x^{1}}{\partial y^{1}}(p) = 1 - \alpha^{1}\Gamma^{1}_{11}$. Is this the right idea? And then we conclude the proof by what we find with the second derivative, plug it into the transformation property of the $\Gamma$'s and utilize symmetry/anti-symmetry.

Comment: if you evaluate at $p$ you shouldn’t  have anything dependent on $\alpha$ anymore. I think you’re still too focused on the final answer. Follow my notation, and calculate the things I asked for in the three bullet points. Your answer should be in terms of $A$’s and $B$’s. There’s a reason I’m getting you to do things with general $A$’s and $B$’s so as to not get confused by symmetrization/anti-symetrization brackets.